# Does an application need root permissions if it modifies files in the "/" directory?

Tags: permissions, application-development, directory, deb

I'm creating a program for Ubuntu that involves creation of files within the folder where the code is present.

What I want to know is: When a **.deb** package is installed, where do the contents go?

If a program makes modifications to or creates new files within the `/...` directory, does it require root privileges?

Comment: Yeah..you need root privileges to create files in root directory.(while installing through .deb we need to run the commands with sudo..so it kinda give permissions for editing )

Comment: You should modify your application to create files at runtime in a dedicated folder in the user's home directory. Maybe we can help you a bit better if you specify what the application does and what kind of files are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly, the directory: `/` is the "root" directory of all directories. That includes all sub- directories, so includes your `home` directory as well.

You need additional privileges for all directories outside `~` (your `home`directory), so either you need to:

- be member of a specific group (e.g. to share files or directories), or, more drastically,
- you need `sudo` privileges

outside your personal `home` directory.

A `.deb` installer, to install items *globally* for all users, will therefore need t be run with `sudo` privileges, since it installs files and executables outside your `home` directory.

#### When a .deb package is installed, where do the contents go?

Although there are quite strict rules for using directories outside your home directory, there is no easy answer to that; it depends on the application, its role and what kind of application it is. See also [here](http://When%20a%20.deb%20package%20is%20installed,%20where%20do%20the%20contents%20go?) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview) (among others).

If you want to get an impression on where files are installed, look inside an unzipped `.deb` installer of a simple application. It contains a scaled version of your system and shows where the files will be "projected" to.